# How to show the related (suggested) keywords?

Tags: sql, sqlite, search

We do a program for cataloging images by assigning keywords (tags) to them.

An image has the following keywords "John", "Jane", "Portrait".

Another image has the following keywords "John", "Jane", "Wedding".

When the user tries to catalog the next image and adds the "John" keyword, we want to appear in the 'Suggested' area the keyword "Jane".

**How can we extract (using SQL) the suggested keywords based on the most possible combinations?**

EDIT START:

Aside the 'John' waiting for 'Jane' keyword example above, I think that a more theoretical formulation is *we want the top 'x' keywords which are to be found together with the already assigned 'y' keywords in assigned past images*

:EDIT END

Note that Images can have more keywords assigned and in 'Suggested' area is best to have more suggestions.

The relevant table is called `TagsTree` and it has the following creation DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE TagsTree(ImageID INTEGER NOT NULL, TagID INTEGER NOT NULL, UNIQUE (ImageID, TagID))
```

...where ImageID is FK to the photo entity and TagID is FK reference to the keyword entity.

Also, any other hints regarding schema etc. are greatly appreciated.

PS: The DB engine is SQLite3, if it matters.

Comment: Please specify what you mean with "most possible combinations".

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be something like the following. For example we will find suggestions for `TagId=$SearchedTagID$`. First we should select all `TagID` which have common `ImageId` with `$SearchedTagID$` and then group by `TagId` and descent sort the result set by count of occurrences of each `TagId`. Also you can limit results by some value (in this example 5 common suggestions (LIMIT 5)).

```
SELECT TagID,
       COUNT(*) as CommonCount
FROM TagsTree
WHERE ImageID IN (SELECT ImageID FROM TagsTree WHERE TagID = $SearchedTagID$)
      AND TagID <> $SearchedTagID$
GROUP BY TagID
ORDER BY CommonCount DESC
LIMIT 5
```